# VSCode isn't running PyLint (pylint runs in terminal fine)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

My Pylint isn't picking up errors in VSCode.

if I run `pylint file.py` in the terminal I get the following ouptut:

```
************* Module file
file.py:38:27: E0001: invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 38) (syntax-error)
```

so I feel like I can be pretty sure Pylint has installed okay

However, in the Problems tab on VS Code, all I can see is "No problems have been found in the workspace so far". I've intentionally made a number of different errors to test it and none of them are being found by Pylint.

In settings, linting is definitely enabled and set to run on save. If I run `CTRL + shift + P` and then choose "Run Linting" I still don't get any problems found.

My settings.json are:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\becky\\anaconda3\\python.exe",
    "files.autoSave": "off",
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.linux": "",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"],
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    },
    "python.linting.pylintCategorySeverity.convention": "Hint",
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": ""
}
```

I'm really lost here, I'd really appreciate any help with this because I'm not too sure where else to look!

Thanks!

Comment: look in the `Python` panel of the `OUTPUT` panels, there the pylint command is shown and its output. Are you sure the `pylint_django` is on your `PYTHONPATH`, try it without these `pylintArgs`

Comment: @Becky Heath -I tested my pylint with the settings you provided. As 'rioV8' said, it was caused by "pylintArgs",(it turned off the display of Pylint). Please comment out the content of "pylintArgs" and the problem can be solved.

Comment: @JillCheng  Thank you tonnes, binning off that line solved my problem straight away! Too much trying to troubleshoot with solutions I don't completely understand I think! Thanks!!

Comment: @rioV8 I tried to tag you in my prior comment but I wasn't allowed - thank you very much!!

Comment: @BeckyHeath Could you possibly write up Jill's solution as an accepted answer?